# Make custom wordpress page the proper way

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, custom-component

I would need to make a few custom pages on a site using wordpress. This involves:

Adding tables into the Database
Making a page that adds entries to the new tables based on a submitted form
making a page that displays those values in a structured way.

What i need:

- To understand how to include this page in the existing layout (header etc..) and having access to the user session, ((custom page template??))
- To understand the PROPER way to access the custom database tables from a custom page keeping in mind point 1,

I have already done things like this in the past but given that i have almost zero experience with wordpress i built a custom mysqli connection for those extra tables. Also the session integration and such have included in a non-proper way. I would like to make things the proper way this time around.

sample table:

```
cabinets

| id | lenght | height | width |
  1      1200    3000     300
  2      1200    2800     600
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your WP directory, wp-content-> themes-> your_theme

make any simple php file

```
<?php
// Template Name: custom_page
get_header();
?>
your custom contents

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then go to WP_ADMIN choose any page or create new page, go to Page Attribute, you will find "`custom_page`" in Template Selction list..

for more details you can check this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

**Edit :**

No need to include or config extra database file, u can call it directly as all connections are already defined in header part.. you just try to add table and write simple query for fetching single result..it will work like charm..good luck..

**EDIT 2**
You can write query according to ur sql or sqli..

```
<?php
// Template Name: custom_page
get_header(); global $data;

$query = "SELECT id,lenght, height, width 
FROM cabinets";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo " ".$row['lenght']. " , " .$row['height']. " , " .$row['width']. " ";
}
?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, does this also give access the custom database tables? does wordpress provide functions to read/write the database?

Comment: yes, when u use get_header(); all data connection automatically allocated..and u can access that database table..

Comment: Great thanks! if you update your answer with that part too showing how to contact the database i mark it as accepted. for now its only 50% of the answer. thank you!

Comment: ehm, why is getfooter commented?

Comment: sorry its mistake..remove that comment "//"

Comment: Ashish, could you please provide an example of a query to a custom table, and how to read user data such as username or id? i am searching since 2 days but cannot find anything.. Thank you!

Comment: plz provide me any custom table name (along with 1-2 table fields) which you have added in your database, so i will give u simple query and its result..

Answer (score 0):

Create custom templplate

```
<?php
/*
   template name:mytemplate
*/
 //get_header();
?>
hhhhhhhhh
<?php //get_footer(); ?>
```

after that  you can select it at any page  to customize accordingly .